# Printer port class

Tags: java

Please is there any native class that has functions for usb printer port updating and control? I'd like to queue print jobs, update and modify print files. Most especially I am hoping java has the solutions cos I'd like to read the data from a mailbox/website and queue them for printing, changing the queue jobs if so desired, even during the printing process

Comment: Google lists a ton of results just typing in "usb printer java"

Comment: Can you provide more details?  What kind of USB printer?  Any/all?  What kind of print jobs in the queue?  Only those submitted by the Java application, or all print jobs on the system?

Comment: The printer is hp2050 desk jet printer and the print jobs will be plain text (strings). I had mistakenly placed this as an answer a long while ago.

Comment: @Austin, rightly said and very helpful. But isn't it better working with the guidance of experts who had grazed a path before? Surely, the path will be easier...

Comment: @GregJava, your question was "Please is there any native class that has functions for usb printer port updating and control?". You're asking for a class name it sounds like. A simple google search like i said would lead you to classes, examples, etc. This site in my mind, is more for after you have tried using the printing functions, and were stuck somewhere.

Comment: True indeed, @Austin